# Windows won't close and have broken locks -- how to fix?

Tags: windows

I've got a lot of windows that won't close all the way, and that have broken locks.  Not sure if they're crappy windows or not -- the previous owner cheaped-out a lot of things.

Anyway, how can I fix this?  It seems like it should be easy to replace the locks, but a lot of the windows won't close enough for the locks to work, and I think that's why they broke.

Another question:  what do I even call this problem?  Not sure what to google.  Are these "sagging"?

Pic below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I won't address the "broken locks" part of the question because the answer is self-evident.

You have what is commonly called a *tilt window* that uses *spiral balance* mechanisms to keep the window up when you open it. Common reasons for these windows to become difficult to fully close are worn or damaged *spiral balances* or worn or damaged *balance shoes*.

The *balance shoe* is a part that rides up and down in a frame channel on the side of the sash, the window sash connects to it at the bottom corners. Sometimes you can just lubricate the channel that the balance shoe slides up and down in, to make it easier to open and close the windows.

Check out [this video](https://youtu.be/oYTuTHmY4Cg) to familiarize yourself with how and where the balance shoe operates. There are many more online informational resources to find by searching *spiral sash balance*.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The broken lock problem is because the windows won't close all the way, probably because there is gunk where the window bottoms out.  Possibly damage.

Trying to lock the locks when the window can't go all the way down is what broke the lock mechanisms; also, they are cheap.

There is typically a "replacment window" manufacturer or three in your town, this is probably one of theirs.  Fair chance a local REAL hardware store (the kind that's been there 100 years and looks like something out of Diagon Alley) will have the lock mechanisms in stock.  Be very careful not to strip the screw holes when retightening.